# Get source code of SoundCloud page with PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, soundcloud, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the HTML source code of a SoundCloud link through PHP, but the https protocol makes it nearly impossible with file_get_contents(). I went with curl, but even though it does connect to SoundCloud, it returns a "track not found" error instead of the actual track page, so I suppose there's some additional protection.

Any help getting over this? I know there must be a way, since tools like http://source.domania.net/ have no trouble when I input an URL like https://soundcloud.com/mild-network/wcbf, for example.

Alternatively, is there any "page source viewer" online that can access https and has an API I could work with?

Hope this isn't too specific.

Comment: Without investigating the site too much - SoundCloud is Javascript-heavy. CURL doesn't really support Javascript. You may want to look at other solutions, like phantomjs. You can invoke phantomjs using PHP then read the results. However, bear in mind that it will require some work with Javascript to succeed.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the source?

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

Comment: I don't want to use their API and wait for two weeks to get an API key just to access one publicly accessible line of metadata